# Interpreting output of cat/proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux

How does one interpret the information printed out by the following command in Linux

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

On my  laptop, I get the following [output](http://pastebin.com/gaeGbymq).

Now it says that there are 4 processors on the system. There is also a field inside the information of each processor field which says cou cores are 2.

Does that mean there are 4 Intel i3's CPU's on my system? What does the  processor field  really mean here?

Comment: How is this a programing related question? Voting to migrate to superuser.

Comment: @talonmies: Well, I'd expect more less average programmer to be able to understand/figure out what CPU machine is using, how much memory it has etc, you know. Though this question is more suitable for superuser anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, no :) You have only one i3 CPU with two cores and enabled hyper-threading. For a detailed information on how to read cpuinfo, see [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120228052111/http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info).

Comment: Your link appears to be outdated.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I hate dead links :(